# jQuery XML loading and then innerfade effect

Tags: jquery, xml, wordpress, dom, jquery-plugins

I think I can explain myself without code, so for brevity's sake here we go:

I am using jquery to pull data from an xml and put it into a ul on the page with each xml entry as a li.  This is working great!

However, what I am trying to do afterwards is use the innerfade plugin to make a simple animation between each of the li's.  It's not working though, as it is still just loading the static list with each item visible (whereas if innerfade was working it would only display the first....then fade into the second, etc)

It's not an innerfade problem however, because if I add the list in manually to the page (not injecting it with jquery) then the innerfade works fine.

I'm relatively new to DOM scripting, so I think I am missing something here.  I'm not quite sure how jQuery sequences everything, and I'm having trouble phrasing my question in a search engine friendly manner so here I am.

Is it possible to have jquery pull the data from xml, then inject it into the page, then have innerfade work it's magic? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

xml code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/playlist.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('song').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('title');
            var date = $(this).attr('artist');
            var message = $(this).attr('path');
            $('<li></li>').html('<span id="an_name">'+name+'</span><span id="an_date">'+date+'</span><span id="an_message">'+message+'</span>').appendTo('#anniversary');

        });
    }
});
```

innerfade code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function(){ 
            jQuery('#anniversary').innerfade({
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 5000,
            type: 'sequence',
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please show us your code so that we can find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah put the innerfade code inside of the complete function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/playlist.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    complete: function(){ 
            jQuery('#anniversary').innerfade({
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 5000,
            type: 'sequence',
        });,

    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('song').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('title');
            var date = $(this).attr('artist');
            var message = $(this).attr('path');
            $('<li></li>').html('<span id="an_name">'+name+'</span><span id="an_date">'+date+'</span><span id="an_message">'+message+'</span>').appendTo('#anniversary');

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: that makes sense.  it's giving me a syntax error on  });,\n  after the complete function....is there a proper way to format this that I am missing?

Comment: got it working! 

complete: function(){ jQuery('#anniversary').innerfade({speed: 1000,timeout: 5000,type: 'sequence'}); },

Comment: Oops you got it!  You can use the complete, success and failure functions to trigger "next actions".

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $(this).attr('title');
```

You should use .find() method intead of .attr()